# Creating a custom AJAX in wordpress plugin (without admin-ajax.php)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking to create a custom AJAX plugin without using the admin-ajax.php. 
For example
"/my-ajax-page/parameter1/parameter2/"
In the plugin I will be using these parameter1 & parameter2 to spit out information.
help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have not given us much info, so all I can recommend is CodeIgniter.  Give us some more detail and maybe we can provide a better answer.

Comment: Ok, so here goes. I have to build a plugin and that plugin will be outputting response of ajax calls. the server environment is such that I cannot use the traditional admin-ajax.php. Therefore I have to do a rewrite and send the request to another page for ex: "/my-ajax-page/parameter1/parameter2/" I do not know how to do this in a plugin.